# why doesn't instanceof work the way it sounds?

Tags: java, variables, types, reference

In Java, the `instanceof` operator will only return `false` if comparing `null`. If you test a reference variable that isn't of the required type, the program fails to compile.
Does this operator effectively only test if a reference is `null` or not? Or is there another use I'm not thinking of?

If not, why not call it `isNull` or something more descriptive?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using `instanceof` incorrectly. Can you post the code that fails to compile?

Comment: You can always cast the reference you are testing to an `Object`. Then it should work the way you expect it to. I imagine the reason why it would give you a compilation error is that if it knows the type at compile time, it makes no sense to test it at run time.

Comment: Can you post your code?  If you're getting a compilation error, then you're probably not using it right. :P

Comment: What is the compile error you see? You probably have some issue referencing the type, e.g. not having the right imports, and that's resulting in the compiler error.

Comment: my question was theoretical. I was under the impression that any circumstance outside of a null reference would fail to compile. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It fails to compile if the comparison can never be true.  For example:

```
"string" instanceof Number
```

This will not compile because the compiler knows that a string can never be a number.  The operator does exactly what one would expect it to do: it tests if the operand is an instance of the specified type.

Returning false when testing a null reference is meant to make the code simpler and more readable.  It prevents you from needing to do this:

```
if (obj != null && obj instanceof Number) {
    ...
}
```

Read this to learn about the operator: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how you came to your conclusion, but the `instanceof` operation will result in `false` when the runtime type of the first operand does not match the type specified by the second operand.

For example,

```
Object t1 = "Hello, World!";
System.out.println(t1 instanceof Number);
```

… prints "false" because t1 is a `String`, not a `Number` or one of its subclasses.

Can you please include your example of an `instanceof` operation that failed to compile? Most likely, this is due to a syntax error.

Comment: ... is an `Integer`, not a `String` *or a subclass of `String`* (kind of a moot point here since `String` is final, but this applies to other classes).

Comment: I imagine the compilation error the OP is talking about is: `Integer t1 = new Integer(0); System.out.println(t1 instanceof String);` which (predictably) gives you an "incompatible types" error.

Comment: @NullUserException I reworked the example to illustrate a more general case.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful when you have a superclass type reference and you want to check if the object is an instance of some subclass:

e.g.

```
public class Sup { }

public class Sub1 extends Sup { }

public class Sub2 extends Sup { }

public void someMethod(Sup sup) {
    if(sup instanceof Sub1) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`instanceof` returns true when you use it agains an instance of the class at its right, or any derived from it. It will return false otherwise.

```
class A { /*...*/ }
class B extends A { /*...*/ }

A objA = new A();
B objB = new B();

boolean test = objA instanceof A;   // test is true
test = objA instanceof B;   // test is false
test = objB instanceof A;   // test is true
test = objB instanceof B;   // test is true
```

The code above will not raise any exception. The following will do, however:

```
objB = (B) objA;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(MyObj instanceof SomeClass)
```

- If left side objet is null= return false
- if left side is not instance of rigth side class then return false
- if left side is instance if right side then return true

Please note, that instanceof usage can be avoided with polymorphism in most cases.